# Mapping audio to video with ffmpeg with metadata length

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using node.js ffmpeg-static to map a video and an audio together.

```
var VideoStream = ytdl(video, { filter: 'videoonly', quality: 'highestvideo' });
var AduioStream = ytdl(video, { filter: "audioonly", quality: 'highestaudio' });

const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
  '-i', `pipe:3`,
  '-i', `pipe:4`,
  '-map', '0:v',
  '-map', '1:a',
  '-c:v', 'copy',
  '-c:a', 'aac',
  '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe',
  '-f', 'mp4',
  '-'
 ], {
  stdio: [
    'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
  ],
});

VideoStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
AduioStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./out.mp4'));
```

The saved file contains both audio and video as expected, But the length of the file is only 4 seconds when using `-movflags frag_keyframe`. Although the video continues after that (00:10 / 00:04)

`-movflags faststart` Never works

How do I automatically or manualy (Ytdl allows me to download the video length)set the length?

Thank you